# Get words out of a file in Ada

Tags: ada

I have a folder with files containing  some text. I am trying to go through all the files one after the other, and count how many times we see every word in the text files. 
I know how to open the file, but once I'm in the file I don't know how to read each word one after the other, and go to the next word.

If anyone has some ideas to guide me it'd be great.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file a line at a time into a string using Get_Line, then break the line up into the individual words.

Comment: +1 - Kinda short, but this is really the only answer here that specifies a level of effort commensurate with the triviality of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, I needed some playtime with the containers.
Using streams is still the best solution for your problem, given the multiple files.

---

**`Text_Search.ads`**

```
Pragma Ada_2012;
With
Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps;

Package Text_Search  with Elaborate_Body is

Text : Constant String :=
  ASCII.HT &
  "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created " &
  "equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable "&
  "Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of " &
  "Happiness.--That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted " &
  "among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the governed" &
  ", --That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive of these " &
  "ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish it, and to " &
  "institute new Government, laying its foundation on such principles " &
  "and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall seem most " &
  "likely to effect their Safety and Happiness. Prudence, indeed, will " &
  "dictate that Governments long established should not be changed for " &
  "light and transient causes; and accordingly all experience hath shewn, "&
  "that mankind are more disposed to suffer, while evils are sufferable, " &
  "than to right themselves by abolishing the forms to which they are " &
  "accustomed. But when a long train of abuses and usurpations, pursuing " &
  "invariably the same Object evinces a design to reduce them under " &
  "absolute Despotism, it is their right, it is their duty, to throw off " &
  "such Government, and to provide new Guards for their future security." &
  "now the necessity which constrains them to alter their former Systems " &
  "of Government. The history of the present King of Great Britain is a " &
  "history of repeated injuries and usurpations, all having in direct " &
  "object the establishment of an absolute Tyranny over these States. To " &
  "prove this, let Facts be submitted to a candid world.";


Package Word_List is New Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps(
    Key_Type     => String,
    Element_Type => Positive
);


Function Create_Map( Words : String ) Return Word_List.Map;

Words : Word_List.map;

End Text_Search;
```

---

**`Text_Search.adb`**

```
Package Body Text_Search is

Function Create_Map( Words : String ) Return Word_List.Map is
    Delimiters : Array (Character) of Boolean:=
  ('.' | ' ' | '-' | ',' | ';' | ASCII.HT => True, Others => False);


    Index, Start, Stop : Positive := Words'First;

begin
    Return Result : Word_List.Map do
        Parse:
        loop
        Start:= Index;
        -- Ignore initial delimeters.
        while Delimiters(Words(Start)) loop
            Start:= 1+Start;
        end loop;

        Stop:= Start;
        while not Delimiters(Words(Stop)) loop
            Stop:= 1+Stop;
        end loop;

        declare
            -- Because we stop *on* a delimiter we mustn't include it.
            Subtype R is Positive Range Start..Stop-1;
            Substring : String renames Words(R);
        begin
            -- if it's there, increment; otherwise add it.
            if Result.Contains( Substring ) then
            Result(Substring):= 1 + Result(Substring);
            else
            Result.Include( Key => substring, New_Item => 1 );
            end if;
        end;

        Index:= Stop + 1;
        end loop parse;

    exception
        When Constraint_Error => null; -- we run until our index fails.
    end return;
    End Create_Map;


Begin
    Words:= Create_Map( Words => Text );
End Text_Search;
```

---

**`Test.adb`**

```
Pragma Ada_2012;
Pragma Assertion_Policy( Check );

With
Text_Search,
Ada.Text_IO;

Procedure Test is

    Procedure Print_Word( Item : Text_Search.Word_List.Cursor ) is
    use Text_Search.Word_List;
    Word : String renames Key(Item);
    Word_Column : String(1..20) := (others => ' ');
    begin
    Word_Column(1..Word'Length+1):= Word & ':';
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( Word_Column & Positive'Image(Element(Item)) );
    End Print_Word;

Begin
    Text_Search.Words.Iterate( Print_Word'Access );
End Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going by individual words, you could read the file a line at a time into a string using Get_Line, and then use regular expressions: [Regular Expressions in Ada?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665461/regular-expressions-in-ada)

Comment: @user2131763: I think it's time for you to crack the books, rather than hanging out on StackOverflow.

Comment: Suggest looking at the Index functions in the Strings packages. They are flexible tools to give you the index of a character (e.g. " " or <anything that isn't in the alphabet>) - then you can slice the string into words using these indexes.

Comment: @user2131763 basic regular expressions work on lines. therefore you dont need to get words. Also Marc C & Brian Drummond make good points.

Comment: Regular expressions are -- quite troublesome; I would recommend NOT using them... in my maintenance/development jobs they very quickly become brittle and unwieldy.

Comment: @Brian: `Find_Token` might be appropriate.

Comment: @Shark8 Correct for the real world. this has the smell of homework and therefore a possibly very good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ada 2012 here's how I would recommend doing it:

1. `With Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Ordered_Maps`.
2. Instantiate a Map with `String` as key, and `Positive` as Key;
3. Grab the string; I'd use either a single string or `stream`-processing.
4. Break the input-text into words; this can be done on-the-fly if you use streams.
5. When you get a word (from #4) add it to your map if it doesn't exist, otherwise increment the element.
6. When you are finished, just run a `For Element of WORD_MAP Loop` that prints the string & count.

There's several ways you could handle strings in #3:

1. Perfectly sized via recursive function call [terminating on a non-word character or the end of input].
2. Unbounded_String
3. Vector (Positive, Character) -- append for valid characters, convert to array [string] and add to the map when an invalid-character [or the end of input] is encountered -- working variable.
4. `Not Null Access String` working variable.

Comment: It may be a bit like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer, but if you are going to do all the work mentioned here, you should consider using [OpenToken](http://www.stephe-leake.org/ada/opentoken.html), which will do all that work for you.

Comment: I tried to get OpenToken to work, but it wouldn't... though that could have been trying to use the Dotnet compiler.

Comment: I have no experience with trying to use it with the .net compiler, and I wouldn't be surprised to find out that you are now the only person who does. :-)  The maintainers might be interested in hearing about your attempt.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it might be nice to have a way to easily read Ada source on the platform, and then use it (i.e. Ada as a scripting language) -- I was originally attempting to use the JVM-compiler to make an applet to read/parse/execute Ada in a script-tag... but the gprmake wouldn't recognize the JVM compiler so I tried DOTNET.